# scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline.get_coeffs

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, spline

Im using UnivariateSpline for some Interpolation of 4560 supporting points.

Now I wanted to get the coeffs with

```
UnivariateSpline.get_coeffs()
```

This Method gives me a one-dimension-array of about 400 coeffs. Which way are they sorted? I want to use them for more calculating in C.

Any ideas?

Comment: A detailed answer to a similar is posted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22488637/getting-spline-equation-from-univariatespline-object/25330648#25330648. This answer provides a means of manually evaluating the spline knots and coefficients, so that you can try to match them up to the inputs used by other programs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does scipy.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline.get\_coeffs return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28573779/what-does-scipy-interpolate-interpolatedunivariatespline-get-coeffs-return)